# How to properly dispose of empty fire extingusher?

Tags: disposal, fire-extinguisher

Bought a small home fire extinguisher (dry chemical), and had to use it for a small stove fire. The needle is in the middle of 'empty', (not all the way, but it appears that the fire extinguisher is of the one time use type, and is non-rechargeable) and the label says to discard if the needle points to empty.

I don't just want to chuck a fairly large metal tank into the weekly trash, even fully discharged does that present a danger? Or, is that the proper method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure I used was:

I fully discharged it into a large bucket/tub, then removed the top (it just unscrewed), separating the valve assembly and nozzle from the metal tank. This ensures the internal pressure is atmospheric pressure.

I then took the parts to my local household waste recycling centre and put the cylinder in the "metal" bin.

The dry-powder I just bagged and put into the household waste (separate bin for non-recyclables)

Answer (score 3):

Many, but not all, can be refilled/recharged. I'd ask the local fire dept who does that, get a quote, and compare it to the cost of buying a  replacement

If not, then if there is any pressure left they might be interested in having it for demo purposes.